# View on top of TextureView: Only Portrait mode works

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen-orientation

I'm making an app that overlays a transparent View (CustomView2) over Camera2 video texture view, allowing to draw with fingers on top of camera view.

Drawing works when in portrait mode, but nothing happens on landscape mode.

I figure my XML is bad.. Can anyone help me with this?

here it is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2video.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.example.android.camera2video.CustomView4
        android:id="@+id/texture2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/texture"
        android:background="#4285f4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/record" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. in Layout Editor I had too add the layout to portrait mode specifically